# What is the best way to zip a file in Swift storage without physically downloading it?

Tags: openstack-swift

We're using openstack swift what is the best way to zip a file which already is uploaded to swift container.

We need to this because we don't want to ideally download this file as it will be quite large in GBs.

Comment: in the docs for this endpoint it says it can change the `Content-Encoding ` `/v1/{account}/{container}/{object}` `Create or update object metadata ` https://developer.openstack.org/api-ref/object-store/index.html?expanded=copy-object-detail,create-or-update-object-metadata-detail#create-or-update-object-metadata

Comment: Hi @sissonb I am looking for something the other way round, where I can specify a zip header to store the zipped value of object in swift.

Comment: Do you have any lead that make you believe this feature exists? I've been working with swift for around 5 years and never heard of something like it.

Comment: Yea I don't know if something exists since there is a way to unzip while storing was looking for something similar.